# how to pass static parameters from route to controller - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have 4 routes:

```
billing

billing/{id}

income

income/{id}
```

I want to use the same `moneyController` for each, but the billing route pass an additional variable like `$route=billing` and the income route `$route=income`
along with the $id when listed.

How would I write this into my routes file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$name = $request->route()->getName();` to get current route name. But your code will be clearer if you would use separate actions for each route instead dynamic behavior. Also, it would be less painfull to make changes when your actions will be more complex.